# Finding the point on a curve that has a tangent slope of 7

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the point on a curve $y=x^2-3x$ that has a slope of the tangent $7$.

So I started first with finding the derivative:

\begin{align*}
 f'(x) &=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^2-3(x+h)-(x^2-3x)}{h}\\
 &=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)(x+h)-3x-3h-x^2+3x}{h}\\
 &=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{x^2+2hx+h^2-3h-3x-3h-x^2+3x}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{h(2hx+h^2-3h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}2x+h-3\\
&=\boxed{2x-3}
\end{align*}

So now I am stuck, unsure of how exactly I can find this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hint : derivative at $x=x_0$ gives you the slope of tangent at $x=x_0$

Comment: Just solve $f'(x)=2x-3=7$.

Answer (score 3):

The tangent slope is same as the value of the derivative, so set $f'(x) = 7$. That means $7 = 2x - 3$. Solve for $x$.

Comment: Ah this was my guess initially but I didn't think I was right. So this makes the point on the curve 5?

Comment: Yes, at $x = 5$ the slope of the tangent and the derivative are both $7$.